# react native - requiring unknown module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I have been trying to load local image files in ListView.

It does work when I hard code:

`return <Image source={require('./public/image1.png')} style={{width: 60, height: 60}}/>`

However, it doesn't work when I read the path of the image like this:

```
var path = rowData.thumbnail;
console.log(path); // './public/image1.png'
return <Image source={require(path)} style={{width: 60, height: 60}}/>
```

or like this:

```
return <Image source={require(rowData.thumbnail)} style={{width: 60, height: 60}}/>
```

with this error message,

> Requiring unknown module"'./public/image1.png'". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".

Could you please give me an advice to read the path from the object? I attached the full code below. Thank you in advance.

```
class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    let data = importedData.map(function(d) {
      return {
        thumbnail: "'./public" + d.thumbnail + "'"
      }
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
    };
  }
  renderRow(rowData) {
    var path = rowData.thumbnail;
    return <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Image source={require(path)} style={{width: 60, height: 60}}/>
    </View>
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if the module source has an export directive inside. Did you try to load the module on nodejs shell?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React-Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) there are a couple of ways to specify where your images come from:

Local Storage:

`<Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')}/>`

Network:

`<Image source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>`

Dynamic strings e.g. `rowData.thumbnail` can only be used for **packaged** images. See this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-160488106).

If your images are loaded into **images.xcassets** on iOS and **res/drawable** on Android you can reference them by the filename like so:

`<Image source={{uri:'thumbnailFileName'}}/>`

or..

`<Image source={{uri:rowData.thumbnail}}/>`

You can also specify placeholders in the same way..

`<Image source={{uri:rowData.thumbnail}} defaultSource={{uri:'placeholder'}}/>`

Working demo - https://rnplay.org/apps/tsiGfQ

Comment: I loaded images in images.xcassets and it returns same error. I can load images when I hard-code the uri or path for require. However, I cannot load through rowData.thumbnail with same error message. I think somehow it cannot read the text value from rowData.thumbnail. How can I approach this problem differently?

Comment: What does rowData.thumbnail return? Are you running in a simulator or on device?

Comment: I think the problem was dynamic strings cannot be accepted by require in react native. I use switch to bandage the problem just for now, but it haven't figured out an ultimate solution yet. Please let me know if you have any ideas. :)

Comment: Does this [RN PLAY](https://rnplay.org/apps/tsiGfQ) help? Obviously I'm using network images for the demo but you could easily replace that with 'thumbnailName' of your images once they are in images.xcassets. I think you will get away with just calling rowData.thumbnail, and there is no need to append the thumbnail name to the path. Images in xcassets can be referenced by their name alone. You don't even need a file extension.